# HTML5 Canvas pie chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, pie-chart

I'm attempting to create a simple pie chart like shown in the graphic below:

[image]

The chart will show the results for a quiz where a user can choose either a, b or c. They're 10 questions and the user can only choose one option per question.

What I want to do is show the pie chart with each segment being a percentage of 100% by passing in the values for either a,b, or c.

I have the following so far:

```js
var greenOne = "#95B524";
var greenTwo = "#AFCC4C";
var greenThree = "#C1DD54";

function CreatePieChart() {
  var chart = document.getElementById('piechart');
  var canvas = chart.getContext('2d');
  canvas.clearRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);

  var total = 100;

  var a = 3;
  var b = 4;
  var c = 3;

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    canvas.fillStyle = "#95B524";
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    canvas.lineWidth = 3;
    canvas.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    canvas.closePath();
    canvas.stroke();
    canvas.fill();
  }
}
CreatePieChart();
```

```html
<canvas id="piechart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

The colors are specific to the size of the segment, so green one is used for the largest and green three for the smallest.

Comment: A little more effort could go a long way. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start with the data and drawing the chart

Answer (score 47):

Even after searching Google and triple-checking my radians values, etc. I was **still** having trouble with this, so I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvYkM/1/) for people to play with as a live example and will post the code below as well. (Update: in the [fiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/ya3ya6/yd3rzo42/), stroke and labels are added also.)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var data = [200, 60, 15]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ["red", "green", "blue"]; // Colors of each slice

for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
  myTotal += data[e];
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(
    canvas.width / 2,  // x
    canvas.height / 2, // y
    canvas.height / 2, // radius
    lastend,           // startingAngle (radians)
    lastend + Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal), // endingAngle (radians)
    false // antiClockwise (boolean)
  );
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (data[i] / myTotal);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: I like this, it's super simple, very light, doesn't require any external scripts like jQuery, etc.  This is good for me because I plan to use hundreds of these loaded in via a partial request lol

Comment: This is great! Can I just add that if you want the segments to start from the midnight position, initialise `var lastend = -1.57`. 1.57 is a quarter the number of radians in a circle. Thanks.

Comment: That's true, but initialize it to `var lastend = - Math.PI / 2`to better indicate what you mean. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I like the previous answer, but I felt it was lacking in code clarity and it didn't really cover how to utilize labels.

I moved the values into a data object array for easy declaration. Other values, like percentage, I explicitly declared as a property on the data object, or as a separate variable. This, I think, makes it easier to read.

The refactoring also made it easier to tie the values to input boxes if that's something you're interested in.

To see what I mean and play with the values check out this CodePen: http://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/pRbZeb

```js
var data = [
  {
    label: "one",
    value: 100,
    color: "white",
  },
  {
    label: "two",
    value: 100,
    color: "skyBlue",
  },
  {
    label: "three",
    value: 100,
    color: "yellow",
  },
];

var total = 0;
for (obj of data) {
  total += obj.value;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var previousRadian;
var middle = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  radius: canvas.height / 2,
};

//background
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(middle.x, middle.y, middle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fill();
//end of background

for (obj of data) {
  previousRadian = previousRadian || 0;
  obj.percentage = parseInt((obj.value / total) * 100);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = obj.color;
  obj.radian = Math.PI * 2 * (obj.value / total);
  ctx.moveTo(middle.x, middle.y);
  //middle.radius - 2 is to add border between the background and the pie chart
  ctx.arc(
    middle.x,
    middle.y,
    middle.radius - 2,
    previousRadian,
    previousRadian + obj.radian,
    false
  );
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(middle.x, middle.y);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = middle.radius / 10 + "px Arial";
  ctx.rotate(previousRadian + obj.radian);
  var labelText = "'" + obj.label + "' " + obj.percentage + "%";
  ctx.fillText(labelText, ctx.measureText(labelText).width / 2, 0);
  ctx.restore();

  previousRadian += obj.radian;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pie chart without using external libraries, using html5 canvas :

[image]

[See the code](http://jsfiddle.net/ya3ya6/yd3rzo42/)

But it's better to use libraries for drawing charts. in `apex-charts` there is an option called `sparkline`, which helps you to remove the extra stuffs and draw a minimal and clean chart.

Here is a clean donut chart using `apex-charts` library. (Extra stuffs are removed with `sparkline` option):

[image]

```
var options = {
  series: [620, 40],
  labels: ['Finished', 'Unfinished'],
  chart: {
    type: 'donut',
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      donut: {
        labels: {
          show: true,
          total: {
            showAlways: false,
            show: true,
            label: 'Total'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
};
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

[See it on codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/vYGZBmj)

Comment: Ideally, code is in the answer itself in case links rot over time. Stack Overflow has a handy [snippet feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to help facilitate this.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before but I was able to solve this problem later.

What I was missing was I was drawing an arch in context and was trying to fill it, due to which the color was spreading all across the circle because now the context was bound only between a radius line from center to the starting point of arch and  the arch to bound the context.

But there was no other boundary the line from the end of arch to the center, as soon as I draw that line using the following:

```
ctx.lineTo(center coordinates of circle);
```

I have a complete boundary of a pie, so now if I fill the color in context it will not get spread inside the whole circle but will be limited to that pie.

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question or offer concrete code or actionable advice to work from.