# Draw arc by angle in SVG

Tags: svg

When I want to draw a pie chart in SVG, all tutorials say that you need to calculate the end point of the arc element. Unless you want an exact 90° angle, that calculated point must unvariably fall *beside* the circumference line of the underlying circle because of rounding, if you scale up the scalable (!) graphic.

I cannot believe there is no way to draw a circle segment by giving a center, a radius and an angle.

Or is there?

Comment: have u looked at this question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle

Comment: In the URL posted by @Fen1kz, the last answer contains this `function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle)`

Comment: @AlvinK. But that is just a JS function that does the calculation. I don't have problems calculating the coordinates. I do know maths. What I find unbelievable is that while SVG *can* do polar coordinates in a circle (using center and radius), it seems to be unable to understand polar coordinates in an arc. This makes no sense at all. That is like calculating three points on the circumference of a circle to define it. Calculating the endpoint of the arc is cumbersome and unnecessary. So I think I must be overlooking the SVG arc element that *does* use a center, radius and angle.

Comment: The issue comes from `<circle>` only draws **full** circles while segments are created from `<path>` using either `arcs` or `bezier curves` (more powerful but makes simple drawing a pain).

Comment: VTC: either this Q isn't seeking an A, or if it is, the A is: [How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a substitute for the ability to create arcs and segments using proper polar co-ordinates, but you can develop quite a workable graphic using stacked circles and [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray).

The way it works is that you set the [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) to the value you want to represent an entire circle, say 100 if you want to work in percentages, or 360 if you want to work in degrees. For these examples I will use 360 to represent degrees.

Then the way that [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) works is that you specify the lengths of successive lines and gaps. So let’s say we want our first circle segment to cover an angle of 90 degrees. We create a circle with a dasharray of `"90 270"`, with 90 being the length (angle) of the dash and 270 being the length (angle) of the gap.

(**Note** that the stroke will be drawn starting in the 3 o’clock position, so I am grouping the circle/s and rotating the group 90 degrees counter-clockwise so that we start in the 12 o’clock position.)

[image]

```css
svg {height: 180px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-600 -600 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="rotate(-90)">
    <circle r="500" stroke="red" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="90 270" fill="#eee"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then let’s say we want our second circle segment to be 135 degrees. We stack a second circle on top of the first, this time with a dasharray of `"0 90 135 135"`, where 0 is the length of the first line (we want this to be invisible), 90 is the length of the first gap (equal to the length of our first segment), 135 is the length of the second line (the one we want to see) and then 135 is the length of the second gap, taking the total to 360.

[image]

```css
svg {height: 180px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-600 -600 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="rotate(-90)">
    <circle r="500" stroke="red" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="90 270" fill="#eee"/>
    <circle r="500" stroke="blue" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 90 135 135" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Continue on and you can segment the entire circle using degrees:

[image]

```css
svg {height: 180px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-600 -600 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="rotate(-90)">
    <circle r="500" stroke="red" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="90 270" fill="#eee"/>
    <circle r="500" stroke="blue" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 90 135 135" fill="none"/>
    <circle r="500" stroke="orange" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 225 75 60" fill="none"/>
    <circle r="500" stroke="black" stroke-width="100" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 300 60" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

For a pie chart, just use a stroke width which is double the radius.

[image]

```css
svg {height: 180px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-600 -600 1200 1200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="rotate(-90)">
    <circle r="250" stroke="red" stroke-width="500" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="90 270" fill="none"/>
    <circle r="250" stroke="blue" stroke-width="500" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 90 135 135" fill="none"/>
    <circle r="250" stroke="orange" stroke-width="500" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 225 75 60" fill="none"/>
    <circle r="250" stroke="black" stroke-width="500" pathLength="360" stroke-dasharray="0 300 60" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

(**Note** that pie charts can also be built relatively easily [in CSS using a conic gradient.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56272424/2518285))

Comment: This is wonderful. I wish I could give you 100 upvotes. Thank you.