# How to create a multi colored circle in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a circle which is divided into 6 sectors based on some values, the angle of the sector is dependent on some parameter. The bigger the value of the parameter, the larger the radians of the circle.

The way I understand it can be built by making a circle which has this 6 different portions, and then put another div on top, which creates this white ring like effect. I know how to create circle, but not able to understand how to dynamically divide it into different colored sectors.

Is this even possible with CSS, does a solution exist using Javascript. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

[image: circle]

Comment: CSS circle with four points - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tupCW/.. I am , however; not aware of any CSS only solution with 6 sectors

Comment: It's most likely possible with a SVG library: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: There won't be any CSS only solution if, as you said, `the angle of the sector is dependent on some parameter`. I understand this parameter to be rather variable - no way to go with CSS.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlage:Sitzverteilung - from there on you will only need different border radii, and a solution for getting 360° (I can only think of one section being larger than 90°). Maybe a `<canvas>` or `<svg>` will fit your needs better - it would definitely be simpler.

Comment: Try this: http://mistercss.blogspot.in/p/pie-chart-generator.html

Comment: @SonuJoshi: When I click on create chart nothing happens

Comment: It was fun :) http://jsbin.com/elozep/1/edit

Comment: @drinchev Wow!!! But its not dynamic in the sense I can change the sector sizes based on certain value

Comment: Yes, for this you'll have to use Raphael or something else ;). I made it just for fun and for answering your original question : "How to create a multi colored circle in html and css"

Comment: @Sachin I fixed it :P Try to Click on Create Chart Again : http://mistercss.blogspot.com/p/pie-chart-generator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
http://html5.litten.com/graphing-data-in-the-html5-canvas-element-part-iv-simple-pie-charts/

It should be noted that I found that once by using google to find this question/answer: [HTML5 Canvas pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995797/html5-canvas-pie-chart/6995830#6995830)

Comment: Thanks for the article, it was very helpful. I am new to HTML5 and didn't google a solution using HTML5

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 Canvas is the way to go. Here are some links to learn:

[W3C Specification](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

[Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/)

Comment: I guess Kinetic.js would be an overkill in this case, since I want a very non-interactive and simple chart. Maybe once we make it more complex we can go for Kinetic.js

Comment: Yeah, this was just an example what you can do with canvas .. of course you do not need a library for something like that ..

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="first" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000;">Your browser       does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
</canvas>

 <p>
  <select name="shapes" id="shapes">
     <option value="Square">Square</option>
     <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <select name="bkcolour" id="bkcolour">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Black</option>
  </select>
</p>

<button onclick="drawshapes()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function drawTenSquare()
    {
   for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
        var x=45;
    var y=25;
    var canvas =document.getElementById("first");
            var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            context.fillRect(x+(i*15),y+(i*5),10,10);
   }
   }

   function drawTenCircle()
   {
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       var canvas=document.getElementById("first");
           var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
           context.beginPath();
           context.arc(95+(i*5),50+(i*2),40,0,2*Math.PI);
           context.stroke();
   }
  }

  function drawshapes()
  {
   var shape = document.getElementById("shapes")
   var index = shape.selectedIndex;
   var valindex = shape[index].value;

   if(valindex == "Square")
   {
    drawTenSquare();
   }
   else if(valindex == "Circle")
   {
    drawTenCircle();
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See This Canvas i guess it will help u in designing or developing of your canvas.

Comment: Tried it in jsfiddle not working, but does give an idea, thanks